# Mostrar una linea desde inicio hasta final de linea después de leer un documento de texto

Tags: java

llevo solo una semana con esto de Java y me han pedido que de un programa que tengo ya hecho, introduzca una palabra en un jTextField y después de pulsar el botón "Buscar", en un jTextArea se muestre la línea en que se encuentra la palabra, no el número, sino el contenido de la frase, es decir si por ejemplo yo pongo en el documento de texto:

> Hola buenas tardes
>   Como se encuentra?

y busco por ejemplo: `buenas`

Se ha de mostrar en el jTextArea que tiene de nombre jtxtarea1:

> Hola buenas tardes

Solo he conseguido que si está la palabra muestre un mensaje de Encontrado y si no esta que muestre no encontrado. El codigo es este:

```
private void btntransferirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   String Documento = txtarea.getText();
   String buscar = userInput.getText();
  if(Documento.contains(buscar)){   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Encontrado");

    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No encontrado");  
    }

}
```

Todo viene de antes, en Documento se guarda lo que hay en el primer jTextArea que es el documento de texto que previamente se busca, y en buscar está lo que introduce el usuario en el jTextField.

Es la primera vez que escribo por aquí porque solo llevo una semana con java y estoy un poco perdido. Sé lo que he de hacer pero no sé cómo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. En tu pregunta hablas de "leer de un fichero", pero en tu código no hay nada que lea de ficheros. ¿Puedes aclarar eso? (Puedes pulsar el botón "editar" para hacer cambios en tu pregunta).

Comment: @SJuan76 Creo que esa parte la tiene resuelta y por eso no la ha añadido

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que ya tienes todo el texto en la variable `Documento` (que debería llamarse `documento`, empezando por minúsculas, si seguimos las convenciones de Java), lo que significaría que tienes hecho lo más complicado.

El problema que tienes que no estás siendo capaz de encontrar una línea, sino que buscas en todo el texto, pero ya tienes parte del trabajo hecho. Lo que tienes que hacer es dividir el texto en sus distintas líneas y buscar en cada línea:

El final de una línea viene dado por el carácter *new line*, que en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación se representa con `"\n"`. Sabiendo esto, puedes simplemente dividir el texto completo en líneas así:

```
String [] lineas = documento.split("\\n");
```

El motivo para poner dos veces el carácter `\` es porque el método [`split​(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) espera que el string que le pases como parámetro sea una expresión regular válida, por lo que entendería ese carácter como que estamos intentando *escapar* (innecesariamente) la n, por lo que tenemos que *escapar el carácter escapador*.

Ahora, puedes buscar en cada línea el texto proporcionado:

```
for (String linea: lineas) {
    if(linea.contains(buscar)){   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, linea); //muestras la línea donde estaba
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Genial @Pablo Lozano! Me ha sido de gran ayuda, era justo lo que necesitaba!
Como ya dije estoy empezando en esto de java y me han mandado algunos trabajos y me han dicho que me vaya buscando la vida y que busque información donde pueda. Creo que no será la única duda que pregunte por aquí.
Hice C y sabía lo del salto de línea del "\n", pero no sabía como podía representarlo y tampoco sabía lo del "String [] lineas". Esto tengo entendido que es un Array, ¿Es lo que se conoce también como puntero?

Muchas gracias!